# Detect when a unique url is accessed for the first time

Tags: python, django

For example say I have a website called `website.com`. When the url `website.com/stackoverflow` is accessed  for the first time, I want to store the value `stackoverflow` in my database. Is this possible, and how would I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use get_or_create and I assume you have defined model for Website

**urls**

```
url(r'^(?P<url_path>\w+)/$', views.home, name='detail'),
```

**views**

```
def home(request, url_path):
    obj, created = Website.objects.get_or_create(path=url_path)
    if created:
        # Do something with created object
```